# Android Map Fragment covers components under it

Tags: android

Currently I'm trying to have a layout that looks like this:
[text field]
[map fragment]
[ad]

However, the map covers any component that comes below it. I'm using essentially the same exact layout as I am in another activity where it is component -> fragment -> ad and that displays perfectly fine. Below is my xml. Thanks for the help!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/query_field"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search for tweets here..." />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        tools:layout="@layout/test"
        map:uiZoomControls="false"
        />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/map_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/list_ad_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit"
    />
```

Edit: Adding `android:layout_weight="1"` to the `RelativeLayout` got it to display correctly. If anyone can explain why or give a better solution that would be awesome. Here's the editted code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/query_field"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search for tweets here..." />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        tools:layout="@layout/test"
        />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/map_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/list_ad_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXXXXX"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing to `RelativeLayout` and using the `layout_above` in your `xml`. That should solve this issue.

Refer following code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/query_field"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search for tweets here..." />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/list_ad_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/list_ad_map">

    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        map:uiZoomControls="false"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        tools:layout="@layout/test" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/map_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work either. However, adding "android:layout_weight="1" to the relative layout did. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Oh Yes, You need to add layout_weight as well. Forgot to mention. glad your problem is solved.